# How to capture the response of ResponseEntityExceptionHandler to create JWE encrypt

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwe, controller-advice

I have springboot based restful web-service. I have CryptoResponseBodyAdvice to capture the response from controller and create JWE out of response body and send JWE as API response.
**public class CryptoResponseBodyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice**

Trouble comes when some exception occurs and request reaches the exception resolver.
In such exception scenario the response is not interfered by **CryptoResponseBodyAdvice
public class ExceptionResolver extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler**

Can you please suggest what kind of ControllerAdvice or something else will help me capture the responses from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler so I can create JWE out of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a request interceptor which implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor, in which you will check the statusCode, if statusCode is more than 400, means it's an exception then you can extract it's response in whatever format it is coming and can create JWE out of that.